# need mapView not to updateLocation

Tags: ios, swift, mkmapview, cllocation

I have got mapView, and its delegate method

```
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView!, didUpdateUserLocation userLocation: MKUserLocation!) {
    mapView.userTrackingMode = MKUserTrackingMode.None
    var eye = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(userLocation.coordinate.latitude, userLocation.coordinate.longitude)
    var cam = MKMapCamera(lookingAtCenterCoordinate: eye, fromEyeCoordinate: eye, eyeAltitude: 10000)

    UIView.animateWithDuration(1, animations: { () -> Void in
        mapView.camera = cam
    })
}
```

and it works some random way. it executes when view loads, and than when I am scrolling map to another country or city and zoom, it can(sometimes, now always) return me to my current location. It is curious cause my current location didnt changes and the delegate shouldnt execute.
I need do somehow this thing DONT HAPPENED. So i want to make my map zoom to current location only when location changed, in other way I need to have free map for scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set you controller as `CLLocationManagerDelegate`, then declare a variable like:

`var locationManager:CLLocationManager = CLLocationManager()`

then in your viewDidLoad method:

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.locationManager.delegate = self
    self.locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
```

It should prevent to call `func mapView(mapView: MKMapView!, didUpdateUserLocation userLocation: MKUserLocation!)`.

Pay attention that you have to re-enbale it in case you need to update map center with your coordinate without manual scrolling to you actual position.

Comment: you didnt understand what I need and trying to do. I want to use delegates, and all this mess, but only in case when userlocation REALLY updates, not when I am scrolling map. Your answer is about another case